# Can go convert an interface type pointer to VALUE in passing function parameter?

Tags: go

When I studied Go by "Go In Action" book, there is a segment code like below.

I haven't learned Go too much in its interface concept.

The segment defines a interface called notifier used to notify people, and two types (user , admin) impl this interface.There is a middleware, says sendNotification(), that uniforms the type who impls notifier interface

What confuses me is the parameter of middleware function sendNotification(), it receives a value (not pointer!) of inferface type(notifier) .But, why uses a pointer to invoke this function in main function:

**sendNodification(&lisa)**

**sendNodification(&bil)**

?? just why?

windows 10. Go 1.12.2

```
package main

import "fmt"

type notifier interface {nodify()}

type user struct {name string;email string}

type admin struct{name string;email string}

func (u *user) nodify (){
    fmt.Printf("sending user email to %s<%s>\n", u.name, u.email)
}
func (u *admin) nodify(){
    fmt.Printf("sending admin email to %s<%s>\n", u.name, u.email)
}

func sendNodification(n notifier){
    n.nodify()
}

func main(){
    bil := user{"Bill", "bill@gmail.com"}
    sendNodification(&bil)
    lisa := admin{"Lisa", "lisa@qq.com"}
    sendNodification(&lisa)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the methods are declared with pointer receivers (`func (u *user) nodify` rather than `func (u user) nodify`), it's the pointer to the type that implements the interface. So you can pass a `*user` to a function accepting a `notifier` because `*user` implements the interface.

Comment: thank you, but is there any convert happen while passing parameter in different type (*user and notifier interface)...  :(

Comment: I konw the compiler can convert a value to pointer when this type implements method in pointer , lik  user.Func() to (&user).Func().

Comment: The interface value holds the value that's passed in. https://tour.golang.org/methods/9